# Using wp-cli, running any command other than --info returns html of site page

Tags: wordpress, command-line-interface, wp-cli

My hosting provider (inMotionHosting) installed wp-cli for me today (since my user account doesn't have the necessary permissions). When I go to my wp root (~/public_html) and run "wp --info" to ensure that it's working, I get the expected output:

```
[~/public_html]# wp --info
PHP binary:     /usr/local/bin/php
PHP version:    5.4.45
php.ini used:   /usr/local/lib/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 0.21.1
```

When I run any other command (even wp help), however, it returns the html sourcecode of our WordPress home page.

I suspect something went wrong in the installation, but the hosting provider seems more than a little clueless regarding wp-cli and I'm hoping to be able to tell them exactly what needs to be fixed.

I've spent the last hour Googling and researching and haven't found anybody else reporting this behavior.

Ideas?